# How to remove timestamp between two phrases?

Tags: bash, sed

Need to delete unique timestamp: **"Thu Apr 11 13:19:02 2019"** from phrase:
**"Log file dated Thu Apr 11 13:19:02 2019 have been imported."** using ONLY **sed** command (required condition).

Note: Please note that input file include two phrases!!!

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88382/using-sed-to-delete-everything-between-two-words

```
/^Log file dated/,/have been imported./{/^Log file dated/!{/have been imported./!d}}
```

Unfortunately this does not work when we have two phrases in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove anything between the two phrases.

```
s/Log file dated .* have been imported./Log file dated have been imported/
```

Answer (score 0):

gnu sed, if the data in 's' file

```
sed -E 's/\s\w+\s\w+\s[123][0-9]\s([0-9][0-9]:?){3}\s[0-9]{4}\b//' s
```

perl,

```
$s= "Log file dated Thu Apr 11 13:19:02 2019 have been imported."
$s =~ s/\s\w+\s\w+\s[123][0-9]\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s\d{4}\b//
print $s
```

just see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help!

Here is another working method found out by my colleague that puts "[TIMESTAMP]" text in place of unique timestamp:

```
s/[A-Za-z]\{3\}.[A-Za-z]\{3\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}/[TIMESTAMP]/g
```

Test in bash console:

```
echo "Log file dated Thu Apr 11 13:19:02 2019 have been imported." | sed 's/[A-Za-z]\{3\}.[A-Za-z]\{3\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}.[0-9]\{1,\}/[TIMESTAMP]/g'

Input text: "Log file dated Thu Apr 11 13:19:02 2019 have been imported."

Output text: "Log file dated [TIMESTAMP] have been imported."
```